# How can i force replace a external js scripts language on the site itself?

Tags: php, javascript

Im using this https://www.gloriafood.com/ service and their translation is very poor. I would like to make adjustments myself. since it comes from an external source i cant really edit any spesific text

Comment: It really depends on how it adds the content. If it's a virtual DOM, you can't.  Have you considered notifying them of their poor translation and offering corrections?